# Recover an unknown from sum of i.i.d. RVs.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, convolution, independence, characteristic-functions

Here is the problem that bugs me:

Suppose two i.i.d. random variables $X$ and $Y$, and random variable $Z$ satisfy:

$$Z = X + aY$$

where $a$ is an unknown constant.

If we happen to know the pdf of $Z$ and $X$ (and $Y$, since they are identically distributed), can we obtain the unknown constant from the given information?

Or any additional assumptions need imposing, so that $a$ can be recovered?

Comment: Yes, something needs to be imposed, since you could have $X=Y=Z=0$. The moment you have something of $Y$ thats not zero, say $E(Y^3)\neq 0$, then $a = E((Z-X)^3)/E(Y^3)$

Comment: @CalvinKhor, thanks for enlightening me! Should it be $a^3 = E((Z-X)^3))/E(Y^3)$?

Comment: oops, yeah. sorry for the error